# Xfce 4.10 not working after hard reset Debian 7.11

Tags: debian, x11, xfce, gui

I had to hard reset my PC. After powering up GUI didn't appear and when I tried to start it, I got `startx: command not found`
Some other commands and their responses:

```
whereis startx
startx:

xfce4-about --V
xfce4-about: Cannot open display
```

Comment: Are you trying to reinstall `xorg` ?

Comment: Should I rund apt-get remove xserver-xorg, apt-get install xserver-xorg, dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg or just apt-get install --reinstall xorg?

Comment: first , run `apt-get install xinit` then configure `xinitrc`

Comment: thanks a lot! Now it works, just one thing that needs to be set up is an automatic start of startx, that's done by the xinitrc configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the `xinit` package:

```
apt-get install xinit
```

Edit `.xinitrc` as follow :

```
#!/bin/sh
exec startxfce4
```

Save it then run `chmod +x .xinitrc`